# Mongodb select multiple tables

Tags: mongodb, select

I'm trying to make something like that:

select  from tableA where ID is in (select id from tableB)

I'm really lost how to do that in MongoDB.

Any help?

Comment: select FIELDS from tableA where ID is in (select id from tableB)

Comment: you will have to do that programmatically. You can use `$lookup` but that comes with performance degradation

Comment: The result agregates an Array with the data. Now, how can I just select them?

Answer (score 0):

[$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) in mongodb allows you to perform left outer join in mongodb on two collections:

Assuming your collection as `TableA` and `TableB` you can use following $lookup query to join data from two collections using foreign key as `IDFromTableA`:

```
db.TableA.aggregate([
   {
     $lookup:
       {
         from: "TableB",
         localField: "IDFromTableA",
         foreignField: "IDFromTableB",
         as: "joined_date"
       }
  }
])
```